# Factory Pattern In Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a class that looks like such:

```
public class SomeRepo : ISomeRepo
{
    private IThingFactory _thingFactory;

    public class SomeRepo (IThingFactory thingFactory)
    {
        _thingFactory = thingFactory;
    }

    public IThing GetThingFromDatabase(int id)
    {

        string thingName = /* some call that gets back some primitives */
        IThing returnVal = _thingFactory.createThing(thingName);

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

So in short, `SomeRepo` is a repo that is responsible for communicating with some datastore to get an `IThing` by Id. And `IThingFactory` is a simple factory that returns a `new IThing` given a string property.

If I am using a Dependency Injection container, should I still be relying on an `IThingFactory`? It seems like I am mixing the two design patterns for the sake of convenience. Is there a more elegant way to construct an `IThing` without the need of a factory or is what I have a good pattern to follow?

Thanks

EDIT: The DI container I am using is Ninject.

Comment: Can you describe `IThing`? How many classes implement it? Is it a simple property bag? Does it contain behavior that you might want to vary?

Comment: `IThing` is only implemented by 1 class but it may be implemented by other classes in the future. It's a single property bag .

Comment: Take a look at [this article about newables and injectables](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IThink is a class that does not need more than the output from the database (so if it need nothing from the DI container) and you dont want to mock it for testing, IMHO you could create the class by calling the constructor.

Otherwise the factory pattern is the right choise in my eyes.

For NInject, there is a [factory extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/) that makes is very easy to create factories - You have just to create the interface and the extension creates the corresponding implementation at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is technique to achieve loose coupling between layers, not exactly what i would describe as a design pattern.

There is nothing wrong with mixing design patterns or using multiple techniques as a general thing to state, unless you are introducing complexity where it is not needed.

So my suggestion is that you approach things by questioning your requirement and understanding the use of design patterns and then you would be able to recognize the need to use a certain pattern to make your code maintainable, extensible or whatever technical requirement you are trying to fulfill.

**Questions i would ask myself:**

What is the problem i am trying to tackle ?

How extensible is this logic going to be ? what are the moving parts and what are the core requirements ?

Which design pattern tackles this kind of issue ?

You also need to weigh between the complexity introduced into the code and time consumed by using certain design patterns and the benefits of using it on short as well as the long run ?